# Using purrr:pmap_dbl to calculate an average for each row of multiple columns (number not known in advance)

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I want to be able to:

(1) write a simple function to calculate the average string-length of a vector of strings

(2) select a bunch of multiple string columns in a data.frame to calculate string-length average over for each row

(3) apply my function using `purrr::pmap_dbl`

I am able to do (1), (2) and (3) with the following:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(q0 = c("a", "b", "c"),
             q1 = c("aa", "bb", "cc"),
             q2 = c("aaa", "b", NA),
             some_other_var = 1:3)

avg_str_len <- function(...) mean(str_length(c(...)), na.rm = TRUE)

df %>%
  mutate(avg_len = pmap_dbl(select(., q0:q2), avg_str_len))

## A tibble: 3 x 5
#  q0    q1    q2    some_other_var avg_len
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>          <int>   <dbl>
#1 a     aa    aaa                1    2   
#2 b     bb    b                  2    1.33
#3 c     cc    NA                 3    1.5

# or if I don't know how many q columns:
df %>%
  mutate(avg_len = pmap_dbl(select(., starts_with("q")), avg_str_len))
```

But I'm especially worried about (1) and (2), respectively:

1. Do I really need such an intricate function? Isn't there a simpler way?
2. Do I really need `select` to choose my multiple columns? Isn't there some `tidyselect` magic like `vars(matches("q"))` or `q0:q3` which could work? (They don't...)

```r
df %>%
  mutate(avg_len = pmap_dbl(q0:q2, avg_str_len))

#Error in q0:q2 : NA/NaN argument
#In addition: Warning messages:
#1: In q0:q2 : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
#2: In q0:q2 : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
#3: In is.data.frame(.l) : NAs introduced by coercion
#4: In is.data.frame(.l) : NAs introduced by coercion

df %>%
  mutate(avg_len = pmap_dbl(vars(matches("q")), avg_str_len))

#Error: Element 1 of `.l` must be a vector, not a `quosure/formula` object
#Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace.
```

*Note there are multiple `q` columns, so selecting them using `list(q0, q1, q2)` is just too long or assume I don't know in advance how many `q` columns I have*

Comment: here you neeed the `select`

Answer (score 2):

One option involving only `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(avg_len = rowMeans(select_if(., is_character) %>%
                         mutate_all(nchar), na.rm = TRUE))

  q0    q1    q2    some_other_var avg_len
  <chr> <chr> <chr>          <int>   <dbl>
1 a     aa    aaa                1    2   
2 b     bb    b                  2    1.33
3 c     cc    <NA>               3    1.5
```

Or if you want only the columns starting with `q`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(avg_len = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("q")) %>%
                            mutate_all(nchar), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks @tmfmnk. Maybe it's a matter of personal taste, but I really like the `pmap_dbl` approach. It seems so weird that there is no way of specifying to `pmap` a bunch of columns using `tidyselect` magic. We both essentially create another data frame within the pipe. I guess we've been spoiled.